# ¿Como mantener la variable capturada mediante un select en una nueva petición?

Tags: javascript

Tengo el siguiente código.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#categoria').on('change',function(){
        var Valor = $(this).val();
        var miVar = $('#idCampoOculto').val();
        console.log('Este es mi sesion ' + miVar);
        
        if (Valor == 1) {
            $("#divIndicaciones").css("display", "block");
            $("#divcontraindicaciones").css("display", "block");
            $("#divEdad").css("display", "block");
            $("#divUnidadTiempo").css("display", "block");

        }else {
          $('#divIndicaciones').hide();
          $('#divcontraindicaciones').hide();
          $('#divEdad').hide();
          $('#divUnidadTiempo').hide();
        
            //alert('esta es la opcion 2')
        }

    });

});
```

Lo que quiero es que al recargase la página de nuevo, no se pierda el valor de la variable, ya que quiero es mostrar unos campos ocultos pero cuando se recarga la página nuevamente los campos desaparecen por que se pierde el valor que tiene la variable.

Comment: Puedes usar localStorage como opción para guardar temporalmente el valor del input.

Comment: Hola, muchas gracias por responder, me podrías dar un ejemplo es que soy un poco novato.

Answer (score 1):

Como bien te han dicho en un comentario, con localstorage se trabaja muy fácil

```
// Para guardar el valor en el localStorage
localStorage.setItem('1', Valor);

// para recoger el valor del localStorage
var Valor = localStorage.getItem('valor');

// y para borrar el valor del localstorage
localStorage.removeItem('valor');
```

Answer (score 0):

Podrías setearla en una cookie-> `document.cookie = "valor="+Valor;`

Y para leerla:

```
var v = document.cookie.split(';')[0].split('=')[1]
```

Por supuesto eso solo funcionará si tu cookie es la primera, ya que document.cookie devuelve un array con las diferentes cookies. Si no es la primera tan solo tienes que recorrer el array buscando la que tenga "valor="